# Creating a List button through Javascript, Issue in replicating the master-detail look up field

Tags: javascript, custom-button

plz suggest.
I have a custom object " Asset" and a child object " Car Accessories" ( master-detail relationship). i have created a custom button " Add New" on car access. object to create a new records,the reason being,,  i want a particular " name" to auto-appear (TBA) as the name in the new records. But even if the names is appearing OK, the related asset ID is not showing in the look up field. can anybody plz suggest where i went wrong?
Below my javascript code for the new button,

window.location.href="/a36/e?retURL=%2F{!Asset.Id}&assid={!Asset.Id}&Name=TBA&00NN0000002GOcY={!Asset.Name}"

[image]

The result being as per below, I am missing the related asset from where i have created the new record. It should appear.

[image]

In the new record the URL showing is as below, The name of the related Asset record is " test" which is showing in the URL but not in the detailed page. plz suggest. Thanks
 https://cs6.salesforce.com/a36/e?retURL=%2F02iN0000001aYvG&assid=02iN0000001aYvG&Name=TBA&00NN0000002GOcY=test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asset field is waiting for an Asset Id. It will show the Asset name automatically.
Here's what i suggest:

```
window.location.href="/a36/e?retURL=%2F{!Asset.Id}&assid={!Asset.Id}&Name=TBA&00NN0000002GOcY={!Asset.Name}&00NN0000002GOcY_lkid={!Asset.Id}"
```

Comment: Hello, Martin. Thanks. I tried this one but till the look up field is not populating. Instead i can see in the URL teh related asset ID "https://cs6.salesforce.com/a36/e?retURL=%2F02iN0000001aYvG&assid=02iN0000001aYvG&Name=TBA&00NN0000002GOcY=02iN0000001aYvG"

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you try this?

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried. But till no success. Although the valus n IDs are appearing in the URL only " https://cs6.salesforce.com/a36/e?retURL=%2F02iN0000001aYvG&assid=02iN0000001aYvG&Name=TBA&00NN0000002GOcY=test&00NN0000002GOcY_lkid=02iN0000001aYvG". The look up is master-details, i hope thts not an issue. Thanks

Comment: How did you get the field Id? Using the Google Chrome console to inspect the field?

Comment: Nope, I went to the related field in the " Car Accessories" object, the API name is Asset__c for the look up field. Here i have taken the ID from the URL " https://cs6.salesforce.com/00NN0000002GOcY?setupid=CustomObjects". Also, if i use the standard button for new record rather than the custom button , this is the URL showing " https://cs6.salesforce.com/a36/e?CF00NN0000002GOcY=test&CF00NN0000002GOcY_lkid=02iN0000001aYvG&retURL=%2F02iN0000001aYvG". Thnx

Comment: Try to inspect the element with the Google Chrome developer mode. You will find the right id here: "<input id='YourId'"

Comment: Hi Martin, I just inspect in chrome. If you talking about this id plz ? But its showing the same ID whaat we have in URL, isnt it. "<input type="hidden" name="save_new_url" id="save_new_url" value="/a36/e?assid=02iN0000001aYvL&amp;00NN0000002GOcY_lkid=02iN0000001aYvL&amp;retURL=%2F02iN0000001aYvL&amp;Name=TBA&amp;00NN0000002GOcY=www">

Comment: I couldnt able to see any input id, anywhere but its <input type> as per my above comment. thnx

Comment: I was talking about the "Asset" input shown in your new page. The last capture you added to your question.

Comment: Hi Martin, Yup, i went to the same page, and then inspect element from chrome, there we have the input type only, that i have pasted above. ths IDs seems similar to the URL ID we were using. If am i right on checking , or u aasking about somthing else ? sry

Comment: Hi Martin, I just changed your suggested code like this, and it worked. Thank you. " window.location.href="/a36/e?CF00NN0000002GOcY={!Asset.Name}&Name=TBA&CF00NN0000002GOcY_lkid={!Asset.Id}&retURL={!Asset.Id}""